# Maven Dependency - Failure to find eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:jar:4.5.1

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-2, soapui

I am running Soapui test using Intelliji, however I am unable to run test via Maven. Normal test works fine using SoapUITestRunner.

I am getting below error, even though I have eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:jar:4.5.1 in my project path and under .m2 repository.

Error:
Failed to execute goal on project webservice: Could not resolve dependencies for project webservice:webservice:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find eviware:maven-soapui-plugin:jar:4.5.1 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Appreciate your help.

Best Regards,
Kam

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>webservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.soapui.plugin.version>4.5.1</maven.soapui.plugin.version>
        <soapui.repo.url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</soapui.repo.url>
    </properties>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
            <url>http://www.soapui.org/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>eviware</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
            <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <!-- Source directory configuration -->
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <!-- Setting properties for test execution -->
                    <properties>
                        <!-- Setting ReportNG listeners -->
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter, org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>eviware</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-soapui-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectFile>${project.basedir}/SoapUIAutomationDemo.xml</projectFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove your cached jars from C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\smartbear.

enable proxy if any in your settings.xml under .m2 folder.